# Initialize an array with last element having key '0'

Tags: php, arrays

I want to initialize an array something like,

```
public $category_arr = array(
                            '1' => 'Page background image', 
                            '2' => 'Page images and graphics', 
                            '3' => 'Page content blocks', 
                            '4' => 'Page actors', 
                            '0' => 'Object priorities'
                      );
```

But since the last value has a key '0', when I use this array in a select box it appears at the top. But I want to it to appear last.

Please help me and let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: where is your `select box` ? and what is `1,2,3,4,0` ?

Comment: either you can do `0,1,2,3,4` or `4,2,3,1,0`

Comment: Are you sorting array before using it in select, which loop you are using to generate select? `foreach` will print in same order, but `for` will start from 0 onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $category_arr = array(
                            '1' => 'Page background image', 
                            '2' => 'Page images and graphics', 
                            '3' => 'Page content blocks', 
                            '4' => 'Page actors', 
                            '0' => 'Object priorities'
                      );
?>
<select>
  <?php foreach($category_arr as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```